# R intersecting strings

Tags: regex, r, intersect

I have the following data as an example:

```
 basketball = c("MISS W. Johnson 18' Pullup Jump Shot",
                "MISS Barnes 12' Pullup Jump Shot",
                "MISS Carter  19' Pullup Jump Shot")
```

How do I find the most common words or 'intersect' them so that I will only have `"MISS Pullup Jump Shot"` as the result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works, but I'm not sure how robust it is given your question is a little vague.

```
Reduce(intersect, strsplit(basketball," "))
#[1] "MISS"   "Pullup" "Jump"   "Shot"
```

Comment: + 1 for Reduce, hadn't seen that before

Comment: Well played.  `Reduce` is a new one to me as well.