# R: data.table count !NA per row

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to count the number of columns that do not contain NA for each row, and place that value into a new column for that row.

Example data:

```
library(data.table)

a = c(1,2,3,4,NA)
b = c(6,NA,8,9,10)
c = c(11,12,NA,14,15)
d = data.table(a,b,c)

> d 
    a  b  c
1:  1  6 11
2:  2 NA 12
3:  3  8 NA
4:  4  9 14
5: NA 10 15
```

My desired output would include a new column `num_obs` which contains the number of non-NA entries per row:

```
    a  b  c num_obs
1:  1  6 11       3
2:  2 NA 12       2
3:  3  8 NA       2
4:  4  9 14       3
5: NA 10 15       2
```

I've been reading for hours now and so far the best I've come up with is looping over rows, which I know is never advisable in R or data.table.  I'm sure there is a better way to do this, please enlighten me.

My crappy way:

```
len = (1:NROW(d))
for (n in len) {
  d[n, num_obs := length(which(!is.na(d[n])))]
}
```

Comment: Like `d[, num_obs := sum(!is.na(.SD)), by = 1:nrow(d)][]` or `d[, num_obs := rowSums(!is.na(d))][]`? (Not sure which would be faster.)

Comment: Yes! this worked.  Could you explain it?  I thought .SD would equal the entire dataset if I used `by = 1:nrow(d)`.  How is it that this does it by row?
edit: also, what exactly does adding the empty chain `[ ]` do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this one using `Reduce` to chain together `+` calls:

```
d[, num_obs := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD,function(x) !is.na(x)))]
```

If speed is critical, you can eek out a touch more with Ananda's suggestion to hardcode the number of columns being assessed:

```
d[, num_obs := 4 - Reduce("+", lapply(.SD, is.na))]
```

Benchmarking using Ananda's larger data.table `d` from above:

```
fun1 <- function(indt) indt[, num_obs := rowSums(!is.na(indt))][]
fun3 <- function(indt) indt[, num_obs := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD,function(x) !is.na(x)))][]
fun4 <- function(indt) indt[, num_obs := 4 - Reduce("+", lapply(.SD, is.na))][]

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(copy(d)), fun3(copy(d)), fun4(copy(d)), times=10L)

#Unit: milliseconds
#          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# fun1(copy(d)) 3.565866 3.639361 3.912554 3.703091 4.023724 4.596130    10
# fun3(copy(d)) 2.543878 2.611745 2.973861 2.664550 3.657239 4.011475    10
# fun4(copy(d)) 2.265786 2.293927 2.798597 2.345242 3.385437 4.128339    10
```

Comment: Nice option.  Plus one.

Comment: Maybe this will eek out some more speed given the OP's description: `indt[, num_obs := 4 - Reduce("+", lapply(.SD, is.na))][]`. I've hard-coded the "4" to avoid recalculation by row.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - it shaved a bit more time off - i've updated the answer above.

Comment: @thelatemail - I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but could you tell me if I have this correct?  `.SD` represents the current subset of data, and if no argument is given in the `i` position in data.table, then `.SD` equals the data for all columns for the _current row_, NOT _all rows_

Comment: @Reilstein - not a dumb question at all. I think `.SD` actually represents the whole data.table if there is nothing in `i` - e.g. `d[,dim(.SD)]` returns a count of both rows and columns.

Comment: @thelatemail - I see, so in that case, in your solution, the `Reduce('+', lapply(.SD,function(x) !is.na(x)))`  statement is saying `+` is the function, and `lapply(.SD,function(x) !is.na(x)))` is turning the rows given by `.SD` into a list to be operated on?  Do I have that right?  I was looking at the `Reduce()` help, and I gathered that it accepts a function, a vector, and an R object, so I am trying to piece together which is which in your solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Reilstein - ignoring the `NA` checking temporarily for explanation's sake,  `Reduce` is taking the parts of the list and doing `(((a + b) + c) + d)` or essentially `a + b + c + d`. Since `+` is vectorised, each part (row) of each vector is added together. Here's another good example of `Reduce` that shows how it can be employed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624284/r-intersecting-strings/22624311

Comment: Okay great, thanks.  I'm beginning to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 10):

The two options that quickly come to mind are:

```
d[, num_obs := sum(!is.na(.SD)), by = 1:nrow(d)][]
d[, num_obs := rowSums(!is.na(d))][]
```

The first works by creating a "group" of just one row per group (`1:nrow(d)`). Without that, it would just sum the `NA` values within the entire table.

The second makes use of an already very efficient base R function, `rowSums`.

Here is a benchmark on larger data:

```
set.seed(1)
nrow = 10000
ncol = 15
d <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(c(NA, -5:10), nrow*ncol, TRUE), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol))

fun1 <- function(indt) indt[, num_obs := rowSums(!is.na(indt))][]
fun2 <- function(indt) indt[, num_obs := sum(!is.na(.SD)), by = 1:nrow(indt)][]

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(copy(d)), fun2(copy(d)))
# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq      max neval
#  fun1(copy(d))   3.727958   3.906458   5.507632   4.159704   4.475201 106.5708   100
#  fun2(copy(d)) 584.499120 655.634889 684.889614 681.054752 712.428684 861.1650   100
```

---

By the way, the empty `[]` is just to print the resulting `data.table`. This is required when you want to return the output from `set*` functions in "data.table".

Comment: This is great, thanks @AnandaMahto !   I am a little bit confused about how you created a group of one row using `1:nrow(d)`.   My initial thought was that this statement would create a group from row 1 to the final row of the file.  I'm clearly missing how the `by` statement works or something.

Comment: My benchmarks suggest this is quicker again: `fun3 <- function(indt) indt[, num_obs := Reduce(\`+\`, lapply(.SD,function(x) !is.na(x)))][]`

Comment: Yeah on my larger data sets, about 115s vs. 0.06s, so a substantial improvement!  Thanks for adding this!

Comment: @Reilstein, out of curiosity, what are the dimensions of your larger dataset?

Comment: the "larger" dataset I was using for some benchmarking was 4 columns, 1.5 million lines.  I eventually will need to run this on something with ~20 columns, 6 million lines, so the speed improvements are a big help :).

Comment: @Reilstein, I would suggest you transfer the check mark so that it draws attention to thelatemail's answer.

Comment: @Ananda sure I can do that.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Here's a version when you need to specify columns:
`d[,num_obs := rowSums(!is.na(.SD), na.rm=T), .SDcols = c('a','b')]`